# Xubuntu 16.04 all icons disappeared after update

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce

All of my icons have disappeared after an update; I tried selecting different icon themes but still no icons are showing up when I log in.

[image: no icons]

Comment: Similar to [No desktop icons after update to 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/475509/no-desktop-icons-after-update-to-14-04)

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in a terminal. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mime cache issue resolved using

`sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`

and performed logout and then login, now all icons are back

Comment: on my Lubuntu 18.04 missing icons on launch bar which I have after reboot during apt update were fixed after second reboot

Answer (score -1):

I add the same !
I was caused by a fail update of linux kernel.
My /boot folder was full.

To check that :
In a terminal, type

df /boot

if it is full (100%), you can clean it using this tutorial :
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/remove-old-kernels-ubuntu-16-04/
Look at "Remove Old Kernels via DPKG".

Et en français :
https://www.justegeek.fr/nettoyer-la-partition-boot-des-kernels-non-utilises-sous-ubuntu/
;)