# All icons have disappeared in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, xubuntu, launcher, icons

I would like to know how to recover all icons in Ubuntu 16.04, because after updating and rebooting the system, the icons just disappeared:

[image: This is the screenshot link]

I followed the instructions of this link, but it didn't work:

[Xubuntu 16.04 all icons disappeared after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769034/xubuntu-16-04-all-icons-disappeared-after-update)

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity

Comment: If it doesn't help, see this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1007213/480481

Comment: I tried the two links, but none of them worked.

Comment: Try this that worked yesterday for someone else with a system broken after 16.04 update: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007026/ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing-after-2-16-2018-update/1007213#1007213

Comment: I just tried that link and it didn't work either.

Comment: I had to reinstall Ubuntu.  The icons are now visible even if I update Ubuntu.  Perhaps, the problem originated from something else.