# Some icons missing in Lubuntu

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, lubuntu, icons

Recently I upgraded Lubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 in my computer and some of the icons have disappeared. Here are two screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb2LE.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G01nl.png

I tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` in the terminal (taken from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769034/xubuntu-16-04-all-icons-disappeared-after-update)), but it didn't worked. What should I do then to have the icons back?

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 (in fact all releases starting with 18.10) state clearly in the release notes, eg. https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/ "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"   Upgrades are possible once you've installed a modern (LXQt) release of Lubuntu, but problems can occur with LXDE -> LXQt upgrades.

Comment: As for fixing your issue, I'll offer https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/System_Tools_and_Preferences.html where I'd start with appearance, changing themes to something LXQt compatible etc... What LXDE setting is fouling up the LXQt desktop you'll have to discover; but compare what you're using with what is a more default Lubuntu/LXQt setup (boot a *live* 20.04 media to see that if you don't have it on a VM or another box maybe)